# Fix React Native not finding Android Studio and Android SDK on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: android, react-native, ubuntu-22.04

When I run npx react-native run-android I get the following error

> Task :app:installDebug
> Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'M2101K6G - 13' for :app:debug

> Task :app:installDebug FAILED
> 38 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 36 up-to-date

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor

when I run npx react-native doctor I get that android studio and android skd are not found

```
 ✓ Node.js - Required to execute JavaScript code
 ✓ yarn - Required to install NPM dependencies

Android
 ✓ Adb - Required to verify if the android device is attached correctly
 ✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
 ✖ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
   - Versions found: N/A
   - Version supported: 33.0.0
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation
```

I have installed everything from react native docs and even from stackoverflow.
this are all my installations

```
jack@linux:~/Android/Sdk$ ls
build-tools    emulator  ndk      platforms       sources        tools
cmdline-tools  licenses  patcher  platform-tools  system-images
```

for for my .bashrc file I have exported them all like this

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/jack/nodejs/bin
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin
```

someone please help coz am not giving up on this process

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.